# Exterior doors with built in blinds? A headache down the road? How to access and fix?

Tags: doors

I'm looking at exterior doors for my house.
I see some that have venetian blinds built in between the exterior and interior panes of glass.
It seems like a good idea...the blinds won't get dusty, no messy ropes on the outside (they have another mechanism).

My question is...am I just setting myself up for headaches later?  If the blinds break, will they be a pain to service?

If so, how do I service them? Will the blinds be easily accessible?

Comment: What does the owner's manual say?  What do online reviews say (or Consumer Reports) about reliability?

Comment: Can't comment about breakage, because ours never have; they're about five years old now. It's a sealed unit, so I guess that if they do break, you're stuffed. The sliders (there are two on each door - to open and close the blind, and to raise and lower the blind) are attached by rare-earth magnets - they don't come off without a fight, and snap back on very easily.